# Nesting LAST_INSERT_ID() in a PDO prepared statement?

Tags: php, pdo, nested, prepared-statement, last-insert-id

Using PHP with MySQL and PDO prepared statements, I would like to mimic an opaque id in a simple, safe and efficient way. The idea is to add a random value to the current value of LAST_INSERT_ID.

```
INSERT INTO table 
SET id = LAST_INSERT_ID( LAST_INSERT_ID() + FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 99)) ), 
text = ?,
...
```

The outer expression sets the id, the inner call gets the current value and modifies it. This works as expected when I test it with the Sequel Pro client. However, in the real script with a prepared statement the last insert id does not get updated/saved. So, I do get random ids, but they are not added up.

What am I missing?

Comment: Define  I do not get it to work

Comment: What you are missing is stating what the actual problem is, i.e. what is not working. I am also assuming the database is some flavor of MySql (you did not say) -- it's the only one I know that has `LAST_INSERT_ID`. My understanding is that by setting an expression value to the call to `LAST_INSERT_ID` you will later be able to call `LAST_INSERT_ID` again with no argument and retrieve the expression. It's not clear the value of that from what you posted.

Comment: And what is `LAST_INSERT_ID()` the first time you do the insert?

Comment: Thanks, I added that. You could say, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` always returns 0. But please be aware that I do not need to fetch that value, it's mainly meant to work internally in the dbms.

Comment: Problem is that LAST_INSERT_ID is only the *last inserted ID for the last statement that client executed*.  So it is not the last value on the database.

Comment: Hmm, okay I'm mixing up LAST_INSERT_ID and auto_increment. Anyways, does it explain the different behaviour of different clients?

Answer (score -1):

This really does not work, and here's why:

- LAST_INSERT_ID() returns 0 on the first call per connection because there is no last insert. Unfortunately, it does **not** just return the potential next AUTO_INCREMENT value.
- If you would split it up into separate commands, first INSERT and then UPDATE within the same statement, LAST_INSERT_ID() would not get updated in between.
- More over, "if you mix references to LAST_INSERT_ID() and LAST_INSERT_ID(expr), the effect is undefined" [Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) vs. [Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-insert-id.html)
- UPDATEd ids will be ignored by LAST_INSERT_ID()

Comment: looks like you are heavily abusing this function.

Comment: Possibly, one of my sentences was poorly written. However, I do not see any point in downvoting, not to mention an explanation for it. This lesson learned might save others from going into the same cul-de-sac. If things do work in some way, it might be worth it to try harder. Thanks to @nigel for the right hint/impulse.